# Getting overloaded file error?

Tags: c++, xcode

working on some c++ homework requiring me to output data into a file then read the data back from it and get the sum of the numbers and the average. This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("test.txt");
    outfile << "28 36 20 36 2 81 12 47/n ";
    outfile << "62 1 29 32 923 39 21 12/n ";
    outfile << "67 23 83 2 10 34 755 23/n ";
    outfile << "24 29 47 7 29 86 426 9/n ";
    outfile << "1 36 76 24 628 12 8 28/n ";
    outfile << "55 29 63 825 51 4 739 34/n ";
    outfile << "38 29 16 923 27 2 84 28/n ";
    outfile.close();

ifstream infile;
infile.open("test.txt");
ifstream read("test.txt");
int num, sum;
read >> num >> sum;

if (read.is_open())
{
    string Array_1[8];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        read >> Array_1[i];
        while (read.good())
        {
            count++;
            sum += num;
            double avg = num/8;
            cout << "Total: " << num;
            cout << "   Average: " << avg;
        }
    }
```

I want the first line of output to be read back to the user and added together. However, next to my counter I'm getting the error: Reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?

I'm still pretty new to c++. Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Off-topic, but you're looping 9 times for an array of 8 elements.

Comment: Slightly more on topic, `using namespace std;` is actively hurting you here, making the error message worse.

Comment: I've never used anything except using namespace std; our professor hasn't taught us that yet. I saw some other people on other questions advising the same thing, but I don't really know how to work around it

Comment: Does the error reference 'count' as the thing that can't be resolved? As I don't see anywhere you declared count, and it might refer to a function in std, which would cause that overloaded error

Comment: @ClaireC, It's recommended to do `using std::string;` for everything you actually use instead of bringing in everything, or to say `std::string` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 2):

You have failed to declare `count` but use this symbol via

```
using namespace std;   // don't ever do that!
count++;
```

So what do you think the compiler will understand `count` to be here? It turns out that there is actually a symbol of that name in the `namespace` you just made globally visible: [`std::count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), which is an overloaded function template. Since this is the only possible candidate matching the name, the compiler tries use it here, but that does not work, hence the error.

To avoid such issues and the resulting incomprehensible error messages, **never** say `using namespace std;`.